# Dropdown search list needs to have a html form with a submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown list that shows the name of different conferences. I can select a certain conference, but as I select the conference, I want to be able to click the submit button so I can get a variable for the conference that was selected.

I'm new with databases, but I have tried adding a form, but I can't seem to get it to work inside of the PHP code. The database connects and shows all of the conferences just fine, I just can't figure out how to get a variable equal to the selected option. The form gets submitted, but I get no value. I have looked all over the web and I have found nothing.

```css
.error {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" />
</head>
<body>  
<form action="" name="selection" method="post">
<select project="ConferenceList" id="ConferenceList" name="ConferenceList">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
//Declare variables
$db_host = "";
$db_username = "";
$db_pass = "";
$db_name = "";
//$db_table = "";
//Connect to phpMyAdmin
$con=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,"$db_name") or die ("No database");

$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * From conferenceList");

echo "<select id='searchddl'>";
echo "<option> -- Search Conference Name -- </option>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option>$row[name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

//Close phpMyAdmin
mysqli_close($con);
?>


<script>
    $( "#searchddl" ).chosen()
</script>


<?php
echo $db_table;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @EdgeDeveloper thanks for cleaning up my code, any suggestions on how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not given `value`attribute in your `<option>` that's the reason nothing is passed in `$db_table` when forms get sumbitted . Instead do like below :

```
  <?php
    //Declare variables
    $db_host = "";
    $db_username = "";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "";
    //$db_table = "";
    //Connect to phpMyAdmin
    $con=mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"$db_name") or die ("No database");


    ?>

    <form action="" name="selection" method="post">
    <select project="ConferenceList" id="ConferenceList" name="ConferenceList">
    <?php 
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * From conferenceList");
    echo "<option> -- Search Conference Name -- </option>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      //when form will get submitted whatever will be in value get passed
        echo "<option value='.$row[name].'>$row[name]</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";

    //Close phpMyAdmin
    mysqli_close($con); ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

     <?php
        $db_table = "";
     //checking if form is submit 
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $db_table = $_POST["ConferenceList"];//will give you value of option selected
         echo $db_table;//printing value 
        }
      ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! The search function doesn't work, but the submitted value equals the selected value, and that is what I wanted! Thanks again, you're a lifesaver!